# Forum data in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, forum

So I am using php to make a simple website for a school project.

For a forum would I do this?

When a new area is created > create a new database
When a new topic in an area is created > create a new table
When a new post in a topic is created > add row to table

When a area is deleted > delete the database
When a topic is deleted > delete the table

etc etc.

Would this be what you do for a forum type scenario?

Comment: You don't add tables or databases after you launched your project. Set up a design that does not need new tables but only new entries

Comment: Nope. 1 table for all "areas", 1 table for all threads, 1 table for all posts

Comment: With that being said, does anyone have any examples then?

Comment: Not code examples, explanation examples

Comment: @SmartLemon why don't you check out the DB schema's for some free open source forums - phpBB comes to mind off the top of my head

Comment: School project... that's why... needs to all relatively my own work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't add tables or databases after you launched your project. Set up a design that does not need new tables but only new entries.

You could do something like this

```
areas (id, name)
topics (id, area_id, name)
posts (id, topic_id, title, content)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your database schema should be pretty much locked in for your normal website operations. You would have a single database, a table for forums, a table for posts, a table for users, etc.

If you search, there are tutorials out there to help get you started. I just found this one: [Creating a simple PHP forum tutorial](http://www.phpeasystep.com/workshopview.php?id=12).