# Max data in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, database

Continuing on from this question here: [Forum data in mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12738292/forum-data-in-mysql-database)

What would be the maximum number of entries I could have in a table without slowinging it significantly down? Because wouldn't querying over 1000-10000 entries just be to much work? Is there a way around this? Or is it fine to put ininte numbers of entries in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the data in question, but 10,000 rows in a table is a *trivial* amount. The key to efficient querying is indexing appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Databases are designed to handle a lot of data. For a decent database 10.000 entries would be *peanuts*.

Databases are also designed with scalability in mind. If the database would become slower for some reason, optimizing the database (with indexies for example) and scaling up hardware will always lead to performance improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately it depends on the performance of the machine running the database, but generally 10,000 records is certainly no problem.  Even relatively small enterprise databases commonly have millions of records.  Speed of select will slow down with large numbers of records; this can be mitigated heavily by adequate indexing.  Indexes, however, will slow down write operations slightly.  There are whole books written on database optimization.